# What is Big O complexity of K-Complementary algorithm below?

Tags: algorithm

I'm implementing efficient algorithm to find K-complementary pairs of numbers in given A array.
I intended to implement O(n) algorithm. And it is O(n) for sure when all numbers in A array are different. However I wonder if it is still O(n) if numbers in A array may be equal, i.e. like in test provided below, where all elements are equal 1. In this test where 3 elements provided we clearly see that we go through external loop 3 times and internal 3 times. However, if A table has n elements where n belongs to set of numbers, than it is untrue that all elements are equal.
That's why I believe complexity of this inner loop is reduced to O(1).

**UPDATED**
Inspired but not fully satisfied with answers to my question I did some deeper research about complexity notation definitions and discovered I wasn't precise with my calculations above.

f(n) = O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and k, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ k. The values of c and k must be fixed for the function f and must not depend on n. 
By definition Big-O gives asymptotic upper bound. It means that if we have worst-case with internal for loop which potentially iterate through n elements than complexity is O(n^2). Even if statistically it is very rare scenario we cannot say that complexity is less than O(n^2). However, what is interesting, if complexity O(n^2) true than O(n^3) is true by definition as well. [Big-O](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation)

Moreover, it is also correct to say that Big-Ω complexity for this algorithm is Ω(n). We use big-Ω notation for asymptotic lower bounds, since it bounds the growth of the running time from below for large enough input sizes. [Big-Ω](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-omega-notation)

To the best of my knowledge we cannot calculate [Big-θ](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-theta-notation) until we tighten Big-O and Big-Ω to the same value.

It might be worth to notice that algorithm below would be linear if it only checked that array contains Complementary Pair. But complexity grows to O(n^2) when it collects all complementary pairs. I watched Google interview presentation with hope to get more clues about topic but they simplified problem to "hasComplementaryPair" function.

Next step about ComplementaryPair algorithm is to find different, faster algorithm, or prove that it can't be done faster.

**End of UPDATED**

```
public class ComplementaryPairs {

    public Set<Pair<Integer, Integer>> process(Integer[] A, Integer k) {
        Set<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairs = new HashSet<>();
        if (A == null) {
            return pairs;
        }

       /*
        *   1. Build differential map.
        * < k - A[i], i >
        */
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            put(map, k - A[i], i);
        }

        /*
         * 2. Collect pairs
         */
        for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
            if (map.containsKey(A[j])) {

                /*
                 * I've wondered if this loop spoils O(n) complexity,
                 * because in scenario where i.e. we have 10 elements in A and every element is the same,
                 * we have to go through 10 elements in external loop and 10 elements in List in HashMap.
                 *
                 * However, if A table has n elements where n belongs to set of numbers, than situation described above is impossible.
                 * In other words I believe complexity of this inner used to be counted as O(1)
                 *
                 */
                for (Integer iIndex : map.get(A[j])) {
                    pairs.add(new Pair<>(j, iIndex));
                }
            }
        }

        return pairs;
    }

    private void put(Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map, Integer key, Integer value) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.get(key).add(value);
        } else {
            /* This may be improved, so List is not created for one element only */
            List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
            list.add(value);
            map.put(key, list);
        }
    }

}
```

Consider test below

```
@Test
public void testWhenArrayContainElementsOfEqualValue() {
    // prepare
    Integer[] A = {1, 1, 1};
    Integer k = 2;

    // execute
    Set<Pair<Integer, Integer>> resultSet = complementaryPairs.process(A, k);

    System.out.println(resultSet);
    // assert
    assertTrue(resultSet.contains(new Pair<>(0, 0)));
    assertTrue(resultSet.contains(new Pair<>(0, 1)));
    assertTrue(resultSet.contains(new Pair<>(0, 2)));
    assertTrue(resultSet.contains(new Pair<>(1, 0)));
    assertTrue(resultSet.contains(new Pair<>(1, 1)));
    assertTrue(resultSet.contains(new Pair<>(1, 2)));
    assertTrue(resultSet.contains(new Pair<>(2, 0)));
    assertTrue(resultSet.contains(new Pair<>(2, 1)));
    assertTrue(resultSet.contains(new Pair<>(2, 2)));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you read this? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/145076

Creating the map is *o(n)* run time but when you write:

```
for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
    if (map.containsKey(A[j])) {
        for (Integer iIndex : map.get(A[j])) {
            pairs.add(new Pair<>(j, iIndex));
        }
    }
}
```

You have a potential complexity of *o(n^2)*. You should try to avoid that and 
then the time complexity is clear.

As for the code, the map will contain key only when there exists i such that *k-A[i]==key*.

Example:

> A=[0,0,0,0,0,0], k=0

Since key 0 has all elements o the array and A[i]=0 for all i for the following example all i satisfy the condition.
So *n^2* is the run time. Big o complexity is *o(n^2)*.

And now some duplications problems are appearing.

Comment: Yes, I read "Better performance" description under link.
Described algorithm is similar to mine but it is simpler because it only return number of occurrences.
I wanted to return pair of indexes of K-complementary elements.
For given example map will contain:
{0=[0], -1=[1], -2=[2], -3=[3], -4=[4], -5=[5]}
where: Key is number value which will be complementary to first number. Value is index to first number in array. 
Result of algorithm is:
[Pair[0,0]]

Comment: @KrzysztofZiomek same complexity. Anyway it was not the questions asked

Comment: In example you provide we go through external loop (O(5)) and then pick element from HashMap which is O(1). I wander how did you came to O(n^2) with this example. I'm looking for some articles to confirm how to calculate complexity of this line with hashmap.

Comment: I suggest you run the example and see for yourself. Be sure to add prints in the beginning of each `for`

Comment: Thank for your answer @Dolev . 
I hope you did notice that I’m not iterating through map itself but through list which is stored as value of map and in given scenario this list contain only one element? 
Map definition is: Map<Integer, List<Integer>>

Let’s see opinion of others as well.
To answer your suggestion, I run it and pasted results above in previous response. To be more specific I paste more detailed logs below.

Ext loop for j= 0
In internal loop add pair [0] [0]
Ext loop for j= 1
Ext loop for j= 2
Ext loop for j= 3
Ext loop for j= 4
Ext loop for j= 5

Comment: @KrzysztofZiomek I gave it another though and edited the answer

Comment: Example A=[0,0,0,0,0,0], k=0 represents worst case and I think we agree on worst-case running time O(n^2). However, it is unusual that all elements in array are the same when element in array is defined as any number. To exemplify what I mean I adduce quicksort algorithm. Quicksort worst-case running time is O(n^2) but best-case and average-case running time is O(nlogn). [link](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/quick-sort/a/analysis-of-quicksort)

Comment: @KrzysztofZiomek the original question was big o and not amortized time. BTW run time is exactly n+number of solutions which is small most the time